# Do I do it correctly (SVN merge and publish)

Tags: svn

I am supposed to publish my changes to trunk. I am using a branch X. I am a beginner to SVN.
I want to do that like this:

- Checkout whole trunk
- Merge with changes from my branch (from the branch repository I would mark my changes int he log)
- Commit the merges in trunk

Is it OK?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caveat: I haven't used SVN for a while!

I think what you suggest will work ok if you specify the relevant revision range for the merge but I always find it easier to do a merge and reintegration on a branch.

You should be merging trunk into your branch regularly and then use the reintegrate option to bring trunk up to date with the branch code once the branch is finished with.

This way you deal with conflicts in the branch, and on a regular basis so the conflicts are usually easier to deal with.